# CSS changes in Chrome Developer's Tools Elements Tab doesn't reflect in Sources when using mapping to a local file

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, sass, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to set up Chrome Developer Tools to edit / save SASS files of my Laravel App. Everything works fine when editing CSS via Sources Tab, however, changes made in Elements pane are not moved to mapped source file.

I was reasoning that it's because SASS path in Elements and Sources panes are not identical. However, Chrome Developer Tools Shows green circle next to file which states that style sheet is mapped to the correct file

I tried modifying SASS Sources map file, so it would include my absolute path, but no matter what Google Developer Tools ads http://127.0.0.1 to the beginning of the path.

However, I might be complete wrong.

Any guidance that would suggest me the further steps to troubleshooting the issue would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!